# Review Snippet on Homepage using Google + Review

Tags: google, google-search, rich-snippets

I am trying to put the Review of my Google + to my Website. How should I do it?
I must be look like this:

[image]

Please Help Me.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for my question but I found the answer on this article: https://www.searchenginejournal.com/google-links-and-reviews-dropped-from-google-search-results/141262/

Google SERP will no longer display the Review Star from the Google + Page.
I am a little late on this one.

Comment: BTW- Thanks for the answer on this! It should help others in the future.